# document.getElementsByTagName doesn't work. How can I get the length of NodeList of body?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get the length or item of body tag.
But, It seems getElementsByTagName doesn't work in terms of NodeList.
How can I do that?

```
 <script type=text/javascript>
 var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');                                                                                                                            
 console.log(b);         // <body>...</body>
 console.log(b.length);  // 0    
 console.log(b[0]);      // undefined
 console.log(b.item(0)); // null
 </script>
```

Thanks.

[Edit]
I added entire body.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type=text/javascript>
 var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');                                                                                                                            
 console.log(b);         // <body>...</body>
 console.log(b.length);  // 0    
 console.log(b[0]);      // undefined
  console.log(b.item(0)); // null
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='test'>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

Place the script at the end of the page, or place it in a function and call it after the entire page has loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Put the script code *after* the body element is closed.  If you try to access an element before it is created, it will not be found.  For example, the following should give you the result you are expecting:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='test'>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
</body>
<!-- script code moved -->
<script type=text/javascript>
 var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');                                                                                                                            
 console.log(b);         // <body>...</body>
 console.log(b.length);  // 0    
 console.log(b[0]);      // undefined
  console.log(b.item(0)); // null
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of all nodes in your document, try: `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` or `document.querySelectorAll('*')`. There is (usually) just one `<body>`-tag in a document, so the length of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')` should be 1.

If you need a list of all elements within the `<body>` of your document, use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagname('*');
```

Comment: Thanks! getElementsByTagName('*') works. But still getElementsByTagName('body').length returns 0.

Comment: Maybe your script is not at the bottom of the page (right before `</body>`. You can move it to there, or apply your script using `window.onload`. Anyway, also see this jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/VmZmB/. In the page jsfiddle generates the scripting is @ the page bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put it AFTER the document has loaded.  You can do so by either placing it at the very end of the body or by not executing the code until an event fires indicating the DOM is ready.  Where you have it in the `<head>` tag, there is no `<body>` tag yet - it hasn't been created.  That's why your code doesn't work in your example (now that you've included the full example).

Once you put the code in a safe place so it executes after the DOM is loaded, your code works perfectly fine for me in Chrome.  I get this output:

```
[<body>​</body>​]
1
<body>​</body>​
<body>​</body>​
```

What is the point of this code?  There is exactly one `<body>` tag and you can reference it any time as `document.body`.

Comment: @KenichiTakano - `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` works for me when you execute the code after the body tag has been created and it won't work if you execute the code before the body tag has been created..

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it doesn't work just because the script was run before the elements were loaded.

change

```
<html>
<head>
<script type=text/javascript>
 var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');                                                                                                                            
 console.log(b);         // <body>...</body>
 console.log(b.length);  // 0    
 console.log(b[0]);      // undefined
  console.log(b.item(0)); // null
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='test'>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

To:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id='test'>
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<script type=text/javascript>
 var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body');                                                                                                                            
 console.log(b);         // <body>...</body>
 console.log(b.length);  // 0    
 console.log(b[0]);      // undefined
  console.log(b.item(0)); // null
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then it will run without problem.